# How to filter/search nested tree returning parent and child

Tags: javascript

I have a nested list that looks something like this:

```
list = {
"name": "first",
"children": [
    "name" : "second",
    "children" : [
        "name" : "third",
        "children" : [...could be nested infinitly]
    ]
],
"name": "a",
"children": [
    "name" : "b",
    "children" : [
        "name" : "c",
        "children" : [...could be nested infinitly]
    ]
],
"name": "test",
"children": [
    "name" : "testChild",
    "children" : [
        "name" : "grandChild",
        "children" : [...could be nested infinitly]
    ]
]
```

}

What I am struggling with is the best way in javascript to query/filter/search with AND OR CONTAINS similar to this:

`Name CONTAINS a AND children > 2 OR name = grandchild`

Which would return:

```
newList = {
"name": "a",
"children": [
    "name" : "b",
    "children" : [
        "name" : "c",
        "children" : [...could be nested infinitly]
    ]
],
"name": "test",
"children": [
    "name" : "testChild",
    "children" : [
        "name" : "grandChild",
        "children" : [...could be nested infinitly]
    ]
]
```

}

Comment: A `javascript` plain object cannot be set to duplicate property names.

Comment: would you like to get a node list with all children or just the nodes without children? btw the data structure is not valid. you need some more objects inside of the arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a constraint function and an iterative and recursive approach for children. The result set returns the first node who match with all properties.

```js
function getList(array, constraint) {
    var result = [];
    array.forEach(function iter(a) {
        constraint(a) && result.push(a);
        Array.isArray(a.children) && a.children.forEach(iter);
    });
    return result;
}


var list = [{ name: "first", children: [{ name: "second", children: [{ name: "third", children: [] }] }, { name: "a", children: [{ name: "b", children: [{ name: "c", children: [] }] }, { name: "test", children: [{ name: "testChild", children: [{ name: "grandChild", children: [] }] }] }] }] }],
    constraint = function (o) {
        return o.name.indexOf('a') !== -1 && (o.children || []).length === 2 || o.name === 'grandChild';
    };

console.log(getList(list, constraint));
console.log(list);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```