# Filter tree recursively based on a custom condition

Tags: javascript

I have below tree structure. I want to filter those items which release = 0.0.1 since I need them to build my navigation according to a specific release number.

```
{
  title: '',
  items: [
    {
      title: '',
      path: '',
      release: '0.0.1'
    },
    {
      title: '',
      path: '',
      release: '0.0.2'
    }
  ]
},
{
  title: '',
  items: [
    {
      title: '',
      items: [
        {
          title: '',
          path: '',
          release: '0.0.2'
        },
        {
          title: '',
          path: '',
          items: [
            {
              title: '',
              path: '',
              release: '0.0.1'
            },
            {
              title: '',
              path: '',
              release: '0.0.2'
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The point is that I need to have the same tree structure because the structure should be consistent when building my navigation.

```
{
  title: '',
  items: [
    {
      title: '',
      path: '',
      release: '0.0.1'
    },
  ]
},
{
  title: '',
  items: [
    {
      title: '',
      items: [
        {
          title: '',
          path: '',
          items: [
            {
              title: '',
              path: '',
              release: '0.0.1'
            },
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I can do this for two levels nested tree as below, but when it comes to more nested levels of `items` it seems that it does not work.

```
const menuToggle = (condition) => (menus) => menus
  .map(menu => ({
    ...menu,
    items: menu.items.filter(item => condition(item))
  }))
  .filter(menu => !isEmpty(menu.items));
```

Comment: A recursive function might be a good start for processing recursive data.

Comment: I found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43692367/how-to-filter-search-nested-tree-returning-parent-and-child but it does not keep the entire node and my original tree structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and a recursive function to recursively build your new array. If the current object has an `items` property, then you can recursively call `menuToggle` to take care of the child items array by filtering it and any of its children. Once the recursive function has returned, you can push an updated version of the filtered items onto the current object using the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) (`...`), which you can then push into your resulting array (`acc`). If the current object doesn't have an items property, you can check to see if it passes the condition, and if it does, you can add it to the accumulated array.

See example below:

```js
const arr = [{ title: '', items: [{ title: '', path: '', release: '0.0.1' }, { title: '', path: '', release: '0.0.2' } ] }, { title: '', items: [{ title: '', items: [{ title: '', path: '', release: '0.0.2' }, { title: '', path: '', items: [{ title: '', path: '', release: '0.0.1' }, { title: '', path: '', release: '0.0.2' } ] } ] }] } ];

const menuToggle = (condition) => (menus) => {
  return menus.reduce((acc, obj) => {
    if(obj.items)
      return [...acc, {...obj, items: menuToggle(condition)(obj.items)}];
    else if(condition(obj))
      return [...acc, obj];
    return acc;
  }, []);
}

const res = menuToggle(({release}) => release === "0.0.1")(arr);
console.log(res);
```

If you also want to remove objects which produce an empty items array, then you can do an additional check for this:

```js
const arr = [{ title: '', items: [{ title: '', path: '', release: '0.0.1' }, { title: '', path: '', release: '0.0.2' } ] }, { title: '', items: [{ title: '', items: [{ title: '', path: '', release: '0.0.2' }, { title: '', path: '', items: [{ title: '', path: '', release: '0.0.1' }, { title: '', path: '', release: '0.0.2' } ] } ] }] } ];

const menuToggle = (condition) => (menus) => {
  return menus.reduce((acc, obj) => {
    if(obj.items) {
      const items = menuToggle(condition)(obj.items);
      return items.length ? [...acc, {...obj, items }] : acc;
    } else if(condition(obj)) {
      return [...acc, obj];
    }
    return acc;
  }, []);
}

const res = menuToggle(({release}) => release === "0.0.1")(arr);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Yes that was my problem with empty items, trying to fix it until you update your answer

Comment: @sadrzadehsina what is the problem? Have you seen my second code snippet?

Comment: Yes your second solution works perfectly. thanks